# One application, two launcher icons on HTC Sense phones

Tags: android, launcher, htcsense

I want to have multiple launcher icons for my application.  I can get this to work fine on some phones simply by adding the following to the Activity definitions

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action
      android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category
      android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't appear to work for HTC Sense phones - I just get the first Activity declared like this.

Anyone know how to do this for HTC Sense too?

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I was just being dumb (always seems to be the case when I ask a question on stackoverflow).  I uninstalled the app and re-installed it and the missing icons appeared.

Phil